# Splitting a string into thirds

Tags: java, string, split, substring

I am making another encoding test... just testing out some of my knowledge where i hit a spike. I know how to split a string into half `String.substring` blah blah... but how do i split into thirds? I wish to save to 3 strings, "firsthalf" "secondhalf" and "thirdhalf" anyone help me?

(Code so far):

```
String text = "abspqrtnf";
    String firsthalf = text.substring(0, text.length() / 3);
    String secondhalf = text.substring(text.length() / 3);
    String thirdhalf = text.substring(text.length() / 3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing on with the way you started:

```
String text = "abspqrtnf";
int textLength = text.length();
String firsthalf = text.substring(0, textLength / 3);
String secondhalf = text.substring(textLength / 3, text.length() / 3 * 2);
String thirdhalf = text.substring(text.length() / 3 * 2);
```

- secondhalf needs to start where the firsthalf ended and 'go' twice as long
- thirdhalf needs to start where secondhalf ended and go to the end

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "abspqrtnf";
String firsthalf = text.substring(0, (text.length() / 3));
String secondhalf = text.substring(text.length() / 3,(text.length()*2 / 3));
String thirdhalf = text.substring((text.length()*2 / 3),text.length());
System.out.println(secondhalf + "   " +firsthalf + "   "+ thirdhalf);
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated you need to decide on what to do if string length is not divisible by 3 (truncate or longer last string) and also cater for an input string less than 3.
Suggest writing some unit tests to cover these use cases. 
Some simple code below as an alternative partial solution.

```
    String input = "abcdefghij";

    if( input.length() >= 3 )
    {
        int singleStringLen = input.length() / 3;
        int index = singleStringLen;

        System.out.println( input.substring( 0, index ) );
        System.out.println( input.substring( index, (index += singleStringLen) ) );
        // last string maybe longer if input string not divisible by 3
        System.out.println( input.substring( index, input.length() ) );
    }
```